# How do I find the length of the longest run in my array?

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I'm trying to write a program to return an integer value of the length of the longest run of repeated numbers. (e.g., an array of integers such as, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6 would return the value 5 since the 5 4's is the longest run.) I've tried writing the code, but it keeps returning the total number of elements in my array. What's going wrong?

```
int length(int array[], int size)
{
   int x = 0, max;
   int result[size];

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      x = i + 1;

      if (array[i] == array[x])
      {
         result[i] = x + 1;
      }

      if (result[i] > result[x])
      {
         max = result[i];
      }
   }

   return max;
}
```

Comment: As a hint - you probably want to keep track of both a current count, and a separate "largest count I've seen so far". Let me know if you'd like a more detailed answer.

Comment: A `max()` function should do it

Comment: You need an array to store the count of each number, not just one paticular.

Comment: u can sort your array , counting sort is a good option if u have small  integer range

Comment: @Nile you are thinking of C++ not C

Comment: @YuHao: If I were to use an array to store the count, rather than just saying "count += 1", would it be something like "array[i] += 1"?

Comment: @Amber: Could I get a more detailed answer please??

Comment: "What's going wrong?" -- Play computer ... step through your routine with a short sample and you'll quickly see that it isn't solving the problem.

Comment: Anyone have an example of how to store the count value into an array? I want to try solving the problem with that method, it sounds like something more along the lines of what we've been learning in class. :/

Comment: If you want to try solving it, then *try solving it*. If you just want the problem solved for you, see my answer below.

Comment: @Karen: In your example identical numbers are grouped together. Why? Why is it `1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4` and not `4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4`? Is it guaranteed that in your input identical numbers are grouped?

Comment: @AndreyT: Oh! They have to be grouped (right after each other) to be considered the longest repeating integer in the array. So something like 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 would still give me three as the return value, even though 2 appears more than 3 in the array. But 3 appears consecutively for a longer period than 2 does.

Comment: @Karen: In that case what you are looking for is called "the longest continuous sequence of identical numbers". Not "the most repeated number".

Comment: @jamylak You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code considers runs of integers, and returns the maximum run length.

```
int length(int array[], int size) {
   int max = 1;
   int current = 1;
   int i;

   for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      if (array[i - 1] == array[i]) {    /* the run continues */
          current++;
          max = current > max ? current : max;
      } else {    /* the run was broken */
          current = 1;
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, how come n was set to array[0]? Couldn't we have said: if (array[i] == array[i + 1])? Why do we say: n = array[i] in the last part of the else statement?

Comment: I didn't comment the variable very well I suppose. I'm using `n` to denote what my current number is.

Comment: This assumes that the array is sorted ... a fact the discernment of which is beyond the OP's current level of expertise, so it's important to state it. Note that thejh already gave an answer that operates on a sorted array ... and said so. (But this code is a bit nicer.)

Comment: Actually good call. `n` isn't really needed. I've refactored the code and eliminated it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I think this was the clearest answer/easiest one for me to understand. :) But thanks to everyone who helped! I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I declared in my post that it considers runs of integers. This also matches with the conditions given in the OP's revised question.

Answer (score 2):

As nachokk said, first sort the values. Afterwards, you can do something like this:

```
int max(int a, int b) { return a>b ? a : b; }

int get_highest_repetitition_length(int arr[], int arr_len) {
  int len = 0, highest_len = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<arr_len; i++) {
    if (i>0 && arr[i-1] != arr[i]) {
      highest_len = max(len, highest_len);
      len = 0;
    }
    len++;
  }
  highest_len = max(len, highest_len);
  return highest_len;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without sorting the values first? And I'm not allowed to use the max() function. :( By the way, this isn't homework, I'm just practicing. :)

Comment: @Karen: I could think of a simple approach without sorting, but that would have an awful complexity class of `O(n^2)`. And, uh, feel free to replace `highest_len = max(len, highest_len);` with `if (len > highest_len) highest_len = len;` or whatever.

Comment: @Karen If this isn't homework, then who isn't allowing you to use max? Note that this answer provides its own max function ... are you not allowed to write functions? To write functions named max? To write functions that find the maximum of their two arguments? I don't know which of these restrictions is being imposed on you, but none of them are sensible or have anything to do with the craft of programming. As for ways without sorting: sure, but they will require a lookup table to map the integers to their counts (this would *not* require O(n*n) unless the lookup is O(n)).

Comment: Oh, the problem wants me to write a single function for the solution.

Comment: @Karen Then the problem is requiring bad programming practice ... I suggest finding a better source of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. If you want to get the result without sorting, you need to know the range of numbers in the input. Let's say the range is from `[0 , size)`.

```
int get_max_rep(int array[], int size) 
{
int* counter = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);    
// initialize
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  counter[i] = 0;
}

int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  ++counter[array[i]];
  if(max < counter[array[i]])
    max = counter[array[i]];
}
free(counter);
return max;
}
```

If the range is [a, b), a < b then you need to do some extra work. Also, if size of array `counter` becomes an issue then you might use a bit-vector as an alternative.

Comment: No, you do not need to know the range of numbers ... and especially in the language your code is written in, which isn't C, and thus -1 for this answer

Comment: Sorry for using new/delete. However, I still think, it is required to know the range of number in order to correctly count maximally repeated number.

Comment: So there are no variable sized containers? No `vector` in C++ or `realloc` in C?

Comment: As it turns out, this is a solution for a quite different problem than the one that the OP meant to pose.